# Getting "neo4j.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'." on installation of Neo4j Server 3.5.7

Tags: neo4j, installation

Trying to upgrade local Neo4j instances and getting errors on start.

Ubuntu 16.04: Trying to upgrade local instances of Neo4j databases which are currently at 3.3.1.

Installed Neo4j Desktop thinking I could do it with that and found the lowest version it upgrades from is 3.4. I now can't remove that. Ubuntu software fails (I just click remove, restart and Neo4j Desktop is still there). dpkg --list doesn't list neo4j desktop, so I can't use "apt-get remove" to remove it.

Uninstalled 3.3.1 and installed 3.3.9 (latest version of 3.3.x).  Started Neo4j and ran fine, updating the database stores to 3.3.9.

Uninstalled 3.3.9 and installed 3.5.7.

Expecting Neo4j to start normally with "sudo service neo4j start", but now getting the following:

```
 neo4j.service - Neo4j Graph Database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/neo4j.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Tue 2019-07-09 14:00:22 BST; 58s ago
  Process: 1417 ExecStart=/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j console (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1417 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 09 14:00:22 doug-ubuntu systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 09 14:00:22 doug-ubuntu systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 09 14:00:22 doug-ubuntu systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 09 14:00:22 doug-ubuntu systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 09 14:00:22 doug-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Neo4j Graph Database.
Jul 09 14:00:22 doug-ubuntu systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 09 14:00:22 doug-ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Neo4j Graph Database.
Jul 09 14:00:22 doug-ubuntu systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 09 14:00:22 doug-ubuntu systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

Checked that I am running JVE 1.8:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.16.04.1-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)
```

Unsure how to proceed.  Any ideas welcome please.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by running "journalctl -e -u neo4j" to view the full error log.  Turns out that it was an APOC jar that was installed for 3.3.x but not compatible with 3.5.x.  Removing the jar file solved it.